# What is a Pythonic way to alter a dict with a key and multiple values to get the desired output?

Tags: python, mysql, list, dictionary

**Problem at hand:**

I have the following list of tuples (ID, Country) that I will eventually store in a MySQL table.

```py
mylist = [(10, 'Other'), (10, 'India'), (10, 'Unknown'), (11, 'Other'), (11, 'Unknown'), (12, 'USA'), (12, 'UK'), (12, 'Other')]
```

I want to treat the 'Other' and 'Unknown' using the following condition :

```
Value       Replaced by => This value
----------------------------------------
Other & Unknown         => Other
A country & Other       => Country
A country & Unknown     => Country
```

**Python :**

```py
def refinelist(mylist):

    '''Updating the list to remove unwanted values'''
    '''
    Other & Unknown => Other
    A country & Other => Country
    A country & Unknown => Country
    '''

    if 'Other' in mylist and 'Unknown' in mylist:
        print 'remove unknown'
        mylist.remove('Unknown')
    if 'Other' in mylist and len(mylist) >= 2:
        print 'remove other'
        mylist.remove('Other')
    if 'Unknown' in mylist and len(mylist) >= 2:
        print 'remove unknown'
        mylist.remove('Unknown')

    return mylist

def main():

    mylist = [(10, 'Other'), (10, 'India'), (10, 'Unknown'), (11, 'Other'), (11, 'Unknown'), (12, 'USA'), (12, 'UK'), (12, 'Other')]

    d = {}

    for x,y in mylist:
        d.setdefault(x, []).append(y)

    # Clean the list values    
    for each in d:
        d[each] = refinelist(d[each])

    ## Convert dict to list of tuples for database entry

    outlist = []

    #result = [(key, value) for key,value in d.keys(), value in d.values()]  ## Couldn't get this to work. Can the below loop be written as list comprehension with minimal footprint?

    for key, value in d.items():
        if len(value) == 1:
            print key, value[0]
            outlist.append((key, value[0]))
        elif len(value) > 1:
            for eachval in value:
                print key, eachval
                outlist.append((key, eachval))

    print outlist

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Output :**

```
remove unknown
remove other
remove unknown
remove other
10 India
11 Other
12 USA
12 UK
[(10, 'India'), (11, 'Other'), (12, 'USA'), (12, 'UK')]
```

**Question :**

I have a feeling this can be done more efficiently. Is using a dict overkill?

I start off with a list of tuples (luples), converting it to a dict, performing a clean operation, then converting it back to luples?

I could just insert the original luples in the MySQL table and then deal with 'Unknown' and 'Other' with few queries but I prefer Python for the task.

A pythonic solution or some critics on the code is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If by "ID" you mean "primary key", aren't you going to end up with duplicate keys in MySQL? Or do you mean something else by "ID"?

Comment: In the database, I enforced a Unique key constraint which is a combination of the ID and the country. 'ID' alone is not the PK. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Making extensive use of generators and list comprehension, you can write it like this:

```python
other = ['Other', 'Unknown']                        # Strings denoting non-contries
ids = set(i for i,j in mylist)                      # All ids in the list
known = set(i for i,j in mylist if j not in other)  # Ids of real countries
outlist = [k for k in mylist if k[1] not in other]  # Keep all real countries
outlist.extend((i, other[0]) for i in ids - known)  # Append "Other" for all IDs with no real country
```

The result will be

```python
[(10, 'India'), (12, 'USA'), (12, 'UK'), (11, 'Other')]
```

If order matters, this will mean more work.

Comment: Are you serious?!! This is awesome. What is the significance of the keyword 'extend' in the last line? Order doesn't matter since it is going in to the MySQL table eventually.

Comment: I like the slicing and dicing of lists and the way you kept it simple. My usage of 'dict' is indeed an overkill! Will try to do a timeit just for kicks.

Comment: @ThinkCode `extend` is like `append` but instead of just adding one items, it adds all the items in the iterable to the list (thus "extending" it).  so `q = [1]` then `q.append([2, 3, 4])` --> [1, [2, 3, 4]] whereas `q.extend([2, 3, 4])` --> `[1, 2, 3, 4]`

Comment: Thanks Jeff! Simple enough. I should stop shying away from new keywords in Python!

Answer (score 2):

For one thing, your code results in a bunch of expensive list operations with each remove call. If order matters, you can do the following, just by sorting first and then going through the list just one more time. (I wrote this as a generator so that you (1) don't have to create a list if you don't need to (e.g. if you were going to add this right into the db) and (2) so that you avoid all the append operations.

```
def filter_list(lst):
    lst = sorted(lst)
    curr_id = lst[0][0]
    found_country = False
    for id, elem in lst:
        if id != curr_id:
            if not found_country:
                yield (curr_id, "Other")
            curr_id = id
            found_country=False
        if elem not in ("Other", "Unknown"):
            yield (curr_id, elem)
            found_country = True
```

Use list(filter_list(input_list)) if you just want to get a list back. (freely admit it's not the most elegant)

Comment: I should have mentioned that the order doesn't matter. Thanks for the explanation. This sure works too. Upvote!

Answer (score 0):

Shorter but probably slower solution:

```
    na_list = ['Other', 'Unknown']
    data = dict()
    result = list()

    for i in mylist:
        k = str(i[0])
        data.setdefault(k, [])
        data[k].append(i[1])

    for k,v in data.iteritems():
       if not len(set(v) - set(na_list)):
           result.append((int(k), na_list[0]))
    else:
       for c in set(v) - set(na_list):
           result.append((int(k), c))
```